# ajax update on confirmdialog close

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4 , I am new to primefaces, I want to update a panel through ajax on close of a confirmdialog  here is my code

```
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure?" header="Perform Action"
            severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure"
                action="#{granteeSelectionManager.confirm}" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" immediate="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Not1 Yet"   
                action="#{granteeSelectionManager.cancelConfirm}"  update="reportingPeriod"
                oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"  />

        </p:confirmDialog>
```

is tried using p:ajax  inside confirmdailog , but it gave error, is there any close event attribute I can Use?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the error message with your post, but i'm guessing that the error is "Unable to attach < p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent" which means that the ajax can only be nested in an UIComponent which implements the ClientBehaviorHolder interface.

I am not sure why you would perform an update when someone closes the confirm dialog, but you could do the update when YES / NO buttons are pressed instead.

You could also disable the close icon by setting the closable="false" attribute, which wuld force the user to press either yes or no

Comment: Yes I finally set closable=false, why I want  to   refresh some parts of my page is I show this confirmdialog on change of singleselectmenu, if dialog is closed then I wan to reset the selection.